# Unprotect a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have protected my sheet with a password and I am trying to use a button that runs a code to copy and paste something in another cell, but when I press the button it says Im not able to do anything because the sheet is protected with the password. How can i use the button and re protect the sheet after the code is run?
Here is the code for the command button

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

'-----Output(FR) button------

'French Note
 Range("P11").Select   Selection.Copy
 Range("P12").Select
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 CheckSpelling


End Sub
```

Comment: Use the [Worksheet.Protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) with the `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` parameter.

Comment: There is also a way to use class modules to unprotect the worksheets so that as soon as the class instance is closed it reprotects the sheet. Have not offered as answer cause I don't recall details and can't find post where I took procedure from. If someone recalls and has documentation can you kindly share it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that **P12** is **Lock**ed and the Sheet is protected.  We unprotect, make changes, then re-protect:

```
Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password = "obvious"
    Range("P11").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("P12").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Selection.CheckSpelling
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password = "obvious"
End Sub
```